# How to get Codeigniter to show all entries and not limit to 10 rows of data in table view?

Tags: codeigniter

I've researched to no avail and hope someone here can help.

Currently the data will get listed in the table as per View below and CodeIgniter automatically limits the the page to 10 rows of data.  ***I do not want this(10 rows of data).***

I need the list of ALL rows to be listed in the table without pagination.

Really appreciate your help.

VIEW code (the entire file):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Appointments</title>
    <?php  $this->load->view("admin/common/common_css"); ?>
    <!-- daterange picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url($this->config->item("theme_admin")."/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker-bs3.css"); ?>">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/favicon.png">
    <?php  $this->load->view("common/secretz_css"); ?>
  </head>
  <body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">

      <?php  $this->load->view("admin/common/common_header"); ?>
      <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
      <?php  $this->load->view("admin/common/common_sidebar"); ?>

      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header  sz-pink">
          <h1>
            TRACKING List
            <small> </small>
          </h1>

        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content ">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="date_range" id="date_range_field" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="date_range_lable" id="date_range_lable" />

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Date range:</label>
                                <div class="input-group"  style="width: 100%;" >
                                  <button class="btn btn-default form-control" style="width: 100%;" type="button" id="daterange-btn">
                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <span id="reportrange"><?php if(!empty($date_range_lable)){ echo $date_range_lable; } else { echo date("M d, Y"); } ?></span> 
                                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                                  </button>

                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>

                        <?php if(_get_current_user_type_id($this)==0){ ?>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Choose a specific Outlet:</label>
                                    <select class="form-control choosen" name="filter_outlet">
                                        <option value="">All outlets</option>
                                        <?php foreach($business as $bus){
                                            ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $bus->Store_Name ?>" 
                                                <?php if($this->input->post("filter_outlet") == $bus->Store_Name)
                                                        { echo "selected"; } ?> ><?php echo $bus->Store_Name; ?></option>
                                            <?php
                                        } ?>
                                    </select>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <label style="line-height: 20px; display: block;">&nbsp;</label>
                            <input type="submit" name="filter" class="btn btn-default " value="Filter" />
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </form>
                <?php $sumH1 = 0; $sumH2 = 0;   ?>
                <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>header 1</th>
                        <th>header 2</th>
                        <th>header 3</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php foreach($business as $list){
                            $this->load->view("admin/tracking_list_row",array("list"=>$list)); 
                            $sumH1 += $list->c_H1;
                            $sumH2 += $list->c_H2;
                        } ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th align="right">TOTAL:</th>
                            <th align="center"><?php echo number_format($sumH1,0,".",","); ?></th>
                            <th align="right"><?php echo number_format($sumH2,2,".",","); ?></th>

                          </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
        </section><!-- /.content -->
      </div><!-- /.content-wrapper --> 

      <?php  $this->load->view("admin/common/common_footer"); ?>  


      <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
           immediately after the control sidebar -->
      <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
    </div><!-- ./wrapper -->

    <?php  $this->load->view("admin/common/common_js"); ?>
    <!-- date-range-picker -->
    <script src="<?php echo base_url($this->config->item("theme_admin")."/plugins/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url($this->config->item("theme_admin")."/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"); ?>"></script>

    <script>
      $(function () {

        $('#daterange-btn').daterangepicker(
            {
              ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Tommorrow': [moment().add(1, 'days'), moment().add(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Next 7 Days': [moment(), moment().add(6, 'days')],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'Next 30 Days': [moment(), moment().add(29, 'days')],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
              },
              startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
              endDate: moment()
            },
        function (start, end) {
          $('#reportrange').html(start.format('MMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMM D, YYYY'));
          $('#date_range_lable').val(start.format('MMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMM D, YYYY'));
          $('#date_range_field').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-D')+','+end.format('YYYY-MM-D'));
        }
        );

        $('#example2').DataTable({
          "paging": true,
          "lengthChange": false,
          "searching": true,
          "ordering": true,
          "info": true,
          "autoWidth": false
        });
        $("body").on("change",".tgl_checkbox",function(){
            var table = $(this).data("table");
            var status = $(this).data("status");
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            var id_field = $(this).data("idfield");
            var bin=0;
                                         if($(this).is(':checked')){
                                            bin = 1;
                                         }
            $.ajax({
              method: "POST",
              url: "<?php echo site_url("admin/change_status"); ?>",
              data: { table: table, status: status, id : id, id_field : id_field, on_off : bin }
            })
              .done(function( msg ) {
              //  alert(msg);
              }); 
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CONTROLLER code:

```
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM daily_sales";

        $q = $this->db->query($sql); 

        $data["business"] = $q->result(); 

        $this->load->view('admin/tracking_list',$data);
```

SCREENSHOT showing the 10 rows displayed (would like to have all 13 entries to be listed here with no pagination):

[image]

Comment: CI doesnt limit anything - show your model code - most likely the cause is there...

Comment: i'm not using model.  the view is called directly from controller.  the sql returns 10 rows of data and actually the 11th row is my total line that i added in view (as updated above).

Comment: apart from the standard that sql is handled in a model, show your full controller, specifically your sql (**as an edit to the question**) as that is where the problem apparently lies. we can't diagnose what we can't see.

Comment: hi @Alex, i edited the question to include the sql call

Comment: there is no `limit` applied to that query, either written or via ci (as other commenter said ci doesn't apply a limit by itself) to only cause only 10 to show up. i would suggest `print_r($data['business'])` in controller and to report that result. if it only shows 10, then recheck your db to see if there really aren't more than 10 rows...

Comment: print_r($business); in the view.

Comment: thanks guys for your time on this.  i've updated the question with a screenshot that shows 13 rows of data and where i get the current pagination.  would really appreciate if i can get your help to get all 13 rows shown in one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following output:

1. Run that query in your db, check if it return 10 rows or more
2. Var_dump or print_r your result() in controller, check if it has more than 10 rows

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT *
           FROM daily_sales";
   $q = $this->db->query($sql); 
   var_dump($q->result());
   //$data["business"] = $q->result(); 
   //$this->load->view('admin/tracking_list',$data);
   ```
3. Var_dump or print_r your $business in view, check if it has more than 10 rows

   ```
   <tbody>
     <?php
       var_dump($business);
       foreach($business as $list){
         $this->load->view("admin/tracking_list_row",array("list"=>$list)); 
         $sumH1 += $list->c_H1;
         $sumH2 += $list->c_H2;
         $sumH3 += $list->c_H3;
       }
     ?>
     <tr>
       ....
     </tr>
   </tbody>
   ```

Like the comments above, CI doesn't auto limit your data, so it should be one of parts above that limit your row of data. I can't comment yet, so forgive me answering here.

Edit:
That's not your CI fault, but your **DataTable** (look [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging)). Change below code:

```
$('#example2').DataTable({
"paging": false, //This one is the cause, change to false
"lengthChange": false,
"searching": true,
"ordering": true,
"info": true,
"autoWidth": false
});
```

Comment: thanks @shira Ishikawa for your time on this.  i've updated the question with a screenshot that shows 13 rows of data and where i get the current pagination.  would really appreciate if i can get your help to get all 13 rows shown in one page.

Comment: @user8367136 Change your "paging" properties in the DataTable javascript to false. That one cause table pagination. You can check the link in my answer.

Comment: brilliant @shira Ishikawa! that works and i accepted your answer.  thank you very much for your help.  really appreciate it.